# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Categories#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I'm new to rails was can't figure out what I'm doing wrong I search around here [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) but nothing seem to be working for me. Any help will be appreciated.

So I get this error ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Categories#show. With the following`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

Following is the code where error is shown.

```
        <a href=""><%= link_to 'Adoption', category_path(@adoption) %></a>
```

Here is my rake routes output

```
          category_subcategories GET    /categories/:category_id/subcategories(.:format)          subcategories#index
                          POST   /categories/:category_id/subcategories(.:format)          subcategories#create
 new_category_subcategory GET    /categories/:category_id/subcategories/new(.:format)      subcategories#new
edit_category_subcategory GET    /categories/:category_id/subcategories/:id/edit(.:format) subcategories#edit
     category_subcategory GET    /categories/:category_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)      subcategories#show
                          PATCH  /categories/:category_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)      subcategories#update
                          PUT    /categories/:category_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)      subcategories#update
                          DELETE /categories/:category_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)      subcategories#destroy
           categories GET    /categories(.:format)                                     categories#index
                          POST   /categories(.:format)                                     categories#create
         new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                                 categories#new
            edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                            categories#edit
                 category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                                 categories#show
                          PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                                 categories#update
                          PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                                 categories#update
                          DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                                 categories#destroy
```

I have the categories along with the subcategories nested in my sidebar. Even if I moved it from the application.html.erb to index.html.erb I still get the same error.

**application.html.erb**

```
  <div class="related">
    <h3>Check Out</h3>
    <br>
    <a href=""><%= link_to 'Adoption', category_path(@adoption) %></a>
      <br>
        <% @adoption.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
        <ul>
          <li><%= link_to subcategory.name %></li>
        </ul>
        <% end %>
```

**categories_controller**

```
def index = Category.all
@adoption = @categories[0]
@missing = @categories[1]
@silly = @categories[2]
end

def show
end
```

**routes.rb** just incase

```
resources :categories do
  resources :subcategories
end
root 'categories#index'
end
```

Thank you everyone and anyone who is able to help me.

Comment: What are you trying to do with two links `<a href=""><%= link_to 'Adoption', category_path(@adoption) %></a>`?

Comment: Hi @Pavan the <a href=""> was from a template I'm using, I just forgot to remove it when I was writing my question. It still gave me the same error when I removed it earlier. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your controller to fill in `@categories` for all actions:

```
before_action :set_categories

def index
end

def show
end

private

def set_categories
  @categories = Category.all
  @adoption = @categories[0]
  @missing = @categories[1]
  @silly = @categories[2]
end
```

Your `application.html.erb` is rendered for *any* action, so you should fill in categories for any action. If you want to render categories only on categories-related pages, move code from `application.html.erb` to `categories.html.erb`.

Comment: Thank you @EugZol I changed all that you say and now everything is working. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. You might consider upvoting my answer as well, if you like it.

Comment: Haha, alright :) Have a good luck traveling into mysterious and rewarding world of Ruby on Rails development :)